# How do I change the location of the apt-get archive?

Tags: apt

I tried this command, but nothing changed. How can I do it?

```
sudo ln -s /media/myFlash/temp  /var/cache/apt/archives
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if you want to make the changes permanent. The solution differs between temporal and permanent.

If you want to make them permanent, try:

```
cd /new/cache/destinantion
mkdir partial
vim /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

Then add this:

```
dir::cache::archives /new/cache/destinantion;
```

For the symlink make sure you have copied and/or moved the archives from `/media/myFlash/temp` to `/var/cache/apt/archives` before creating the symlink. The creation of the symbolic will ***delete*** your current cache.

Here is a good post I found that can help you: *[Change an apt cache folder location](http://abz89.wordpress.com/2010/02/11/change-an-apt-cache-folder-location/)*

Comment: ty , it works .

Comment: Works! Please edit the string "moved the archives from /media/myFlash/temp to /var/cache/apt/archives" to "moved the archives from  /var/cache/apt/archives to /media/myFlash/temp"